# Multisampled texture is blank when saved to image (DirectX)

Tags: c#, directx, direct3d, sharpdx, multisampling

**UPDATE:** this issue turned out to be a silly typo (see answer), which was clearly identified by the DirectX debug layer after I was able to enable it. However, I'm leaving the question up as I think the `SaveContentsToImage` code might be a useful reference for others wishing to export a multisampled texture.

---

I'm trying to save the contents of a multisampled texture (from the swapchain) to an image. I'm using Direct3D with feature level 11.0 via [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/). I have code (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21245876/2274765) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47422139/2274765)) that works fine when the swapchain is initialized with the SampleDescription count set to 1 (no multisampling), but setting the count to 2, 4, etc. to enable MSAA results in a blank image.

My save-to-image function uses [ResolveSubresource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476474(v=vs.85).aspx) to resolve the multisampled texture from the swapchain into a non-multisampled intermediate texture, then uses [CopyResource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476392(v=vs.85).aspx) to copy the intermediate texture into a staging texture with CPU read access enabled. Here's the code:

```
private void SaveContentsToImage()
{
    // TODO breaks when using MSAA.

    D3D11.Texture2D backBufferTexture = _swapChain.GetBackBuffer<D3D11.Texture2D>(0);

    // Intermediate texture used to resolve source using MSAA (unnecessary if source sample count is 1).
    D3D11.Texture2DDescription intermediateTextureDesc = backBufferTexture.Description;
    intermediateTextureDesc.SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0);
    intermediateTextureDesc.Usage = D3D11.ResourceUsage.Default;

    D3D11.Texture2D intermediateTexture = new D3D11.Texture2D(_d3dDevice, intermediateTextureDesc);

    _d3DDeviceContext.ResolveSubresource(backBufferTexture, 0, intermediateTexture, 0, backBufferTexture.Description.Format);
    //_d3DDeviceContext.ResolveSubresource(_renderTargetView.Resource, 0, intermediateTexture, 0, backBufferTexture.Description.Format); // Works identically to above.

    D3D11.Texture2DDescription copyDesc = backBufferTexture.Description;
    copyDesc.SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0);
    copyDesc.Usage = D3D11.ResourceUsage.Staging;
    copyDesc.BindFlags = D3D11.BindFlags.None;
    copyDesc.CpuAccessFlags = D3D11.CpuAccessFlags.Read;

    D3D11.Texture2D copyTexture = new D3D11.Texture2D(_d3dDevice, copyDesc);

    _d3DDeviceContext.CopyResource(backBufferTexture, copyTexture);

    DataStream dataStream;
    var dataBox = _d3DDeviceContext.MapSubresource(copyTexture, 0, 0, D3D11.MapMode.Read, D3D11.MapFlags.None, out dataStream);

    DataRectangle dataRectangle = new DataRectangle
    {
        DataPointer = dataStream.DataPointer,
        Pitch = dataBox.RowPitch
    };

    Bitmap wicBitmap = new Bitmap(_wicFactory, copyTexture.Description.Width, copyTexture.Description.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppBGRA, dataRectangle);

    byte[] pixelData = new byte[copyTexture.Description.Width * copyTexture.Description.Height * 4];
    wicBitmap.CopyPixels(pixelData, copyTexture.Description.Width * 4);
    System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(copyTexture.Description.Width, copyTexture.Description.Height);
    BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, copyTexture.Description.Width, copyTexture.Description.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
    Marshal.Copy(pixelData, 0, bitmapData.Scan0, pixelData.Length);
    bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

    bitmap.Save("test.png");

    Console.WriteLine("Saved image.");
}
```

Here's how the swapchain is configured:

```
ModeDescription backBufferDescription = new ModeDescription(RenderAreaWidth, RenderAreaHeight, new Rational(60, 1), Format.B8G8R8A8_UNorm);

SwapChainDescription swapChainDescription = new SwapChainDescription()
{
    ModeDescription = backBufferDescription,
    SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(SampleCount, 0),
    Usage = Usage.RenderTargetOutput,
    BufferCount = 1,
    OutputHandle = _renderForm.Handle,
    IsWindowed = true,
};
```

`SampleCount` is an integer constant set to 1, 2, 4, etc. If it's set to 1, `SaveContentsToImage()` generates an image that matches what gets rendered to the screen; if it's a higher value, the resulting image is blank.

Comment: Have you enabled the Debug Device and looked for output messages?

Comment: Assuming you mean the debug layer, doing so requires installation of the "Graphics Tools" Windows Optional Feature (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32828880/2274765)). Due to my company's security policies this requires IT intervention. I submitted a ticket two days ago and intend to enable the debug layer once I'm able to do so.

Comment: That would indeed be the first step to finding out the cause here.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll update the question once I'm able to enable the debug layer and check its output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was eventually able to get the features required for use of the DirectX debug layer installed (in addition to the Graphics Tools optional feature, developer mode must also be installed and enabled).

Once I was able to use the debug layer, I set it to break on all message severity levels except information:

```
D3D11.InfoQueue infoQueue = _d3dDevice.QueryInterface<D3D11.InfoQueue>();

infoQueue.SetBreakOnSeverity(D3D11.MessageSeverity.Corruption, true);
infoQueue.SetBreakOnSeverity(D3D11.MessageSeverity.Error, true);
infoQueue.SetBreakOnSeverity(D3D11.MessageSeverity.Message, true);
infoQueue.SetBreakOnSeverity(D3D11.MessageSeverity.Warning, true);
```

There was an error in the call to `CopyResource` in `SaveContentsToImage`:

> D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11DeviceContext::CopyResource: Cannot invoke CopyResource with a mismatch between the source Resource Multisampling (Samples:4, Quality:0) and the destination Resource Multisampling (Samples:1, Quality:0). [ RESOURCE_MANIPULATION ERROR #286: COPYRESOURCE_INVALIDSOURCESTATE]

At this point I felt rather silly. The `CopyResource` call was `_d3DDeviceContext.CopyResource(backBufferTexture, copyTexture)` when it should have been `_d3DDeviceContext.CopyResource(intermediateTexture, copyTexture)`. Evidently I neglected to update this line after adding the intermediate texture to support multisampling.